# How to get the TeamCity working dir in a powershell build step

Tags: powershell, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

In my TeamCity project I have a PowerShell build step, I need to get the current working dir of team city in the script. I tried this code to get it from the environment variables, however, the environment variable is apparently `null`:

```
"Working Dir: " + $env:teamcity_build_workingDir
```

How can I access the TeamCity variables, or how can I get the current working path of the TeamCity project?

Comment: try `pwd` which is an alias for `Get-Location`

Comment: Get-Location / pwd is formatted output from which you had to parse the path.

Answer (score 3):

According to TeamCity [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters), there are no environment variable for the `teamcity.build.workingdirectory`-property.

> **System Property Name**: teamcity.build.workingDir
>
> **Environment Variable Name**: none
>
> **Description**: Working directory where the build is started.
>   This is a path where TeamCity build runner is supposed to start a
>   process. This is a runner-specific property, thus it has different
>   value for each new step.

You could try `$pwd` or `Get-Location` which returns PowerShell's current working directory. Hopefully the PowerShell process was started in the same working directory as the build-runner. Ex:

```
"Working Dir: " + $pwd
"Working Dir: " + (Get-Location)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myDirectory = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.myinvocation?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

For your PowerShell build step, you can make that set an environment variable before running your code. e.g. if you normally want to run `my-script.ps1` you can change the build step to "source code" and then use something like

```
$env:TEAMCITY_BUILD_WORKINGDIR = "%teamcity.build.workingDir%"
. "./my-script.ps1"
```

Then you can use `$env:TEAMCITY_BUILD_WORKINGDIR` inside of your script(s).